# Streaming audio to a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, speech-recognition, speech

I am trying to create a neural network that performs speaker recognition. I would like to be able to serve it such that it takes streaming audio - i.e. I want to perform partial recognition on 100ms frames and then calculate an average at the end.

I would like to know which of the following two forseeable options is the best.

- Training the network on audio clips of 100ms
- Using audio clips of arbitrary lengths and feeding subsequent 100ms segments into some sort of recurrent network. I was thinking that similar to text analysis, maintaining some state information could be useful in real time speaker identification.

Does anyone have some guidance in this regard? Thanks.

Comment: This might really be better over at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) as there doesn't seem to be a code element to the question

Comment: Will do, I take it that SO is typically for the implementation of a model as opposed to its conceptual architecture?

Comment: Typically yes, that's the topic split, if you had TensorFlow or PyTorch code you were trying to debug it would be better over here for instance.